# Integer list as query clause param

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, parameters

I have a ruby app with query to postgresql and I have a problem with param list. I have numbers of ids which I need to search for in database.

Error I got is about string/integer param type.
How to correctly set query param for postgresql?

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "91,147,149,150,152,140,160,121,125,161"
LINE 1: ...= '2018-05-19 21:59:59.999999') AND (items.id IN ('91,147,14...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "items".* FROM "items" INNER JOIN taggings ON taggings.taggable_id = items.id INNER JOIN tags on taggings.tag_id = tags.id WHERE "items"."venue_id" = $1 AND "items"."is_active" = $2 AND "items"."category_id" IN (SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "report_categories" ON "categories"."id" = "report_categories"."category_id" WHERE "report_categories"."report_id" = $3) AND ("items"."state" IN ('queued','published','archived')) AND (found_at >= '2018-05-01') AND (found_at <= '2018-05-19 21:59:59.999999') AND (items.id IN ('91,147,149,150,152,140,160,121,125,161'))):
```

As you can note place where the error shows is `items.id IN ('91,147,149,150,152,140,160,121,125,161'))`

```
if report_tags
  tolist = JSON.parse(report_tags).join(',').gsub(/"/, '').sub!(/^,/, '')
  scoped = scoped.joins("INNER JOIN taggings ON taggings.taggable_id = items.id INNER JOIN tags on taggings.tag_id = tags.id").where("items.id IN (?)",  tolist)
end
```

Thanks to Harald I just needed to update it little bit and it works perfect!

```
if report_tags
  tolist = JSON.parse(report_tags).reject { |e| e.to_s.empty? }
  scoped = scoped.
    joins("INNER JOIN taggings ON taggings.taggable_id = items.id INNER JOIN tags on taggings.tag_id = tags.id").
    where("tags.id IN (?)", tolist)
end
```

Comment: Get rid of the single quotes in `('91,147,149,150,152,140,160,121,125,161')`. These make a single string out of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
if report_tags
  tolist = JSON.parse(report_tags)
  scoped = scoped.
    joins("INNER JOIN taggings ON taggings.taggable_id = items.id INNER JOIN tags on taggings.tag_id = tags.id").
    where(id: tolist)
end
```

Comment: hmm in variable that I set into query there are no single quotes, but somehow they show up at running query

Comment: Can you include the code to generate the query in your question? Likely the is some quoting logic in there.

Comment: Thank you very much @Harald.   I just updated it little bit and it works!